# How to open div when select the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a PSD like this.

[image: PSD]

I want to when select the check box open like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/#multiple-targets .

I see this demo

[image: This is my PSD]

Accordion is Important. I want to PSD to bootstrap 4.5

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <b>درخواست شغل</b>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="change_jobs">قصد انتخاب یا تغییر شغل دارم</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="change_jobs" name="change_jobs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#change_jobs" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="change_jobs">
                <div class="collapse" id="change_jobs">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="job_group">گروه شغلی</label>
                                <select id="job_group" name="job_group">
                                    @foreach ($job_groups as $job_group)
                                        <option value="{{ $job_group->id }}">{{ $job_group->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="how_cooperate">نحوه همکاری</label>
                                <select id="how_cooperate" name="how_cooperate">
                                    @foreach ($how_cooperates as $how_cooperate)
                                        <option value="{{ $how_cooperate->id }}">{{ $how_cooperate->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone please suggest where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Use jquery to toggle class, the active class has `display: block`, default is `none`, if checkbox is checked toggle class.

Comment: Can you send complete code? for example.

Comment: You can learn from this https://codepen.io/hardiksolanki/details/BKrKGa

Comment: But I want it with `accordion`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.slide()` function in jQuery.
By defining listener to see when checkbox is check, the div or whatever you want to [toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp) will hide/show.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $( "p" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });
        }
        else{
              $( "p" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="display:none;">Watch me come and go.</p>

<input type="checkbox">Toggle
```